# Изменение массивов в python

Tags: python, list

Есть проблема с этим кодом

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[1] = 120
print(a)
```

Она заключается в том, что массив a изменяется вместе с массивом b.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого можно избежать?

Answer (score 0):

Операция `b = a` присваивает переменной `b` ссылку на список, которая хранится в переменной `a`. То есть после присвоения обе переменные указывают на один список. Избежать этого можно присвоением ссылки на копию списка: `b = a[:]`.

Comment: Ещё  `b=list(a)`, так сказать, канонический вид.